# Struts DB query execution error

Tags: struts, ibm-rad

I am trying to insert a data to my db2 9.7 database from IBM RAD 7.5 using struts 1.3
But when I execute the query I got this errors:  http://pastebin.com/3UPTVKbh

```
KayitBean kayit=(KayitBean)form;

     //String name = kayit.getName();
     String name="endee";
     DBConn hb = new DBConn();
     Connection conn =hb.getConnection();
     System.out.println("basarili");


     //String sql = "SELECT * FROM ENDER.\"MEKANDENEME\"";
     String sql = "INSERT INTO ENDER.\"MEKANDENEME\" VALUES (\'endere\' ,\'bos\');";
     System.out.println(sql);
      System.out.println("basarili2");

      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      System.out.println("basarili3");
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


    //  String ender=rs.getArray(1).toString();
    System.out.println("basarili4");
   // System.out.println(rs);
     conn.close();
```

I am receiving this after  System.out.println("basarili3");"
Please help me.

Comment: The problem ("The path of an ForwardConfig cannot be null") is Struts(1) related, seems totally unrelated to the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do (apparently) with DB, just with Struts (please correct the title),and the code posted seems irrelevant.

Googling for "The path of an ForwardConfig cannot be null", you'll find [this](http://byvivek.blogspot.com/2007/07/path-of-forwardconfig-cannot-be-null.html).
Check your Struts configuration, and discover if you are using validation or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. My problem was a simple wrong bracket before forward. But it was interesting that i was getting exception always while executing the query.